# 2D Array from user column number input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to make a 2D array using the following:

- User selects a number of random numbers to be included in array
- User selects a number of columns to place those numbers in for the 2D array

The output looks as follows:

230  234  240  245   311

334  396  398  402   415

415  415  425  445   450

450  451  462  467   488

496  513  516  521   534

548  553  560  566   567

570  571  575  579   579

591  597  611  618   620

629  630  638  648   662

where the user in this case would have entered 5 as the number of columns. They can choose any number up to a specific number! This means I can not just enter 5 as the column number, but it must be based off their input. Snippets of my code are shown here (pulled out of different packages/classes, but the only applicable code for this specific problem):

```
public class NumberGenerator {
    private ArrayList<Integer> numbers;
    private Random randomGenerator;

System.out.print("\nEnter the number of numbers (maximum 5000) you would like: ");
        input = this.scan.nextLine();
        int userOption = Integer.parseInt(input);
        while (userOption > 5000 || userOption < 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter the number of numbers (maximum 5000) you would like: ");
            input = this.scan.nextLine();
            userOption = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } this.userNumber.generateNumbers(userOption);

System.out.print("\nEnter the number of numbers per line (maximum 12): ");
        input2 = this.scan.nextLine();
        int userOption2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);
        while (userOption2 > 12 || userOption2 < 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter the number of numbers per line (maximum 12): ");
            input2 = this.scan.nextLine();
            userOption2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);
        } this.userColumns = (userOption2);
```

The rest of my coding and solutions are tested and running, so I know these are working snippets of code. Just need some help figuring out how to code a new method to call the 2D array as shown for formatting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What I understood from your question is: user will input a size of the number list say 500.Then you generate 500 random numbers. Then user again input the column size say 5. then the numbers should be printed 5 per line as output. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. User inputs size of the list, then the number of columns to display the list on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you generated the required list of numbers and you have the required column size. Then you can print the out put using the following method:

```
static void format(List<Integer> numberList,int columnSize){

        int totalLength = numberList.size();
        int index=0;
        for(; (index+columnSize) <= totalLength ;index+=columnSize ){
            System.out.println(String.format(getRowFormat(columnSize), numberList.subList(index, index+columnSize).toArray()));
            //or use this
            //System.out.printf(rowFormat.toString()+"\n", numberList.subList(i, i+columnSize).toArray());
        }
        if(index <= totalLength){//to handle pending values if any.
            System.out.println(String.format(getRowFormat(totalLength - index), numberList.subList(index, totalLength).toArray()));
        }
    }
    //handling format
    private static String getRowFormat(int columnSize) {
        StringBuilder rowFormat = new StringBuilder();
        for(int j=0;j<columnSize;j++){
            rowFormat.append("%10d");
        }
        return rowFormat.toString();
    }
```

call this from your code as:

```
format(numbers,this.userColumns);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The only error I'm getting is that "List cannot be resolved to a type" for the first line "static void format(List<Integer> numberList, int columnSize). The ArrayList for numbers is another class called NumberGenerator.

Comment: `import java.util.List`